# Having trouble trying to expand a partition on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, gparted

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 VM that was partitioned with only 15gb of space that we need to expand. The VM is running on ESXi 6.0.

I've tried booting into a Ubuntu Live CD and using gparted to expand the partition but I'm running into issues because when I boot into the CD it inserts itself as /dev/sda2 and a swap of /dev/sda5. As a result, I'm not able to expand /dev/sda1 using the available space which is now below /dev/sda5.

I tried moving the space to be beside /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda5 but no matter what I do I'm not able to get it to expand /dev/sda1.

Below is a screenshot of things in gparted.

[image: Gparted]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Move the linux swap to right of unallocated and then resize your main partition.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I can move the unallocated space to the left of the swap but only if I make it part of sda2 and then it still won't let me move it to the left of sda2 since it is now part of that.

Comment: What if you delete the swap and then recreate it? It might be needed for you to relink the swap later but thats a very easy thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable swap. Do it in gparted by right-clicking the swap partition and using the context menu. Or run in terminal

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

Then you will be able to move all partitions.

1. Expand `sda2` right.
2. Move `sda5` right.
3. Shrink `sda2` moving its left side right.
4. Expand `sda1`.

Comment: This seems like it should be so simple but it won't let me do that. I have swap disabled and when I try to move sda2 right it won't let me. I can add the unallocated space to expand sda2 but it won't let me move it to the left of sda2.

Comment: OK. First expand `sda2`, then move `sda5` right. Then move left side of `sda2` right. You will have unallocated between `sda1` and `sda2`.

Comment: It won't let me do that now because the unallocated space is located inside of sda2 so I can't move it to the right of space that is within it.

Comment: You can't move unallocated space. You can move partitions. I updated my answer. You need to move `sda5` inside `sda2` first.

Comment: Your updated answer might be working. I'll let you know in just a minute.

Comment: Yeah, that worked. Bah, so simple...should have been able to figure that out without posting on here. Thank you for your help!!!